# Drought-tolerant grass for sunny, wet Texas clay

Tags: plant-recommendations, grass, clay

I live in Texas, and my back yard is on the bottom of a hill; thus it gets lots of run-off from other houses in the subdivision.  The run-off causes problems you'd normally expect:

- Soft, boggy lawn especially in the shallow [drainage swales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swale_%28landform%29) that were put around the house to deflect downhill run-off
- Tough to keep grass looking good because foot traffic easily flattens it (due to high moisture content in the clay).  We have a young child, and it would be nice to have BBQs / backyard kiddie-pool parties that didn't cause lawn damage.

I have considered planting St Augustine, which has a good reputation in hot, boggy soil, but there is another problem.  St Augustine requires a lot of water, and our area of Texas has had problems with [drought](http://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/).

Is there any other grass that will accomplish all of the following?

1. Tolerate drought without a lot of water
2. Stabilize persistently-damp clay soil

Our house faces south, so the lawn is on the north side of the property (if that matters).  We do have a mature Spanish Oak on one side of the lawn (the tree gives some shade to a corner).

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the best solutions to a drainage problem is to divert water, re-grade the slope, and/or improve the soil.  That said, these solutions are not always possible.

My suggestion for suitable plants would be to try Carex praegracilis:
[image: Carex praegracilis at San Marcos Growers]

> A short, rich-green sedge selected by John Greenlee as an alternative
>   to turf grass. Growing to 6-8 inches tall and spreading by rhizomes to
>   form a carpet that tolerates moderate foot traffic. A good plant as a
>   solid ground cover, between and around stepping stones or mixed with
>   other bulbs, perennials and grasses to create a natural meadow look.
>   It tolerates full sun to partial shade but has a period of summer
>   dormancy in warmer, drier climates. Moderate water requirements make
>   this plant not quite drought tolerant but certainly lower than most
>   lawn grasses. It is hardy to at least 10 F and likely to come back
>   from the underground rhizomes after lower temperatures.
>   from [San Marcos Growers](http://www.smgrowers.com/products/plants/plantdisplay.asp?plant_id=2370)

Another possibility is Carex divulsa [C. tumulicola, Hort.]:
[image: Carex divulsa at San Marcos Growers]

> It is a very versatile plant for use in coastal full sun to fairly
>   deep shade. It tolerates boggy wet soils but is also fairly drought
>   tolerant once established.
>   from [San Marcos Growers](http://www.smgrowers.com/products/plants/plantdisplay.asp?plant_id=352)